# Do two polynomials $A$ and $B$ share a root when $AP+BQ=0$ for some polynomials $(P,Q) \neq (0, 0)$ with $\deg P < \deg B$, $\deg Q < \deg A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, resultant, common-root

## My question

Let $A$ and $B$ be polynomials of degrees $d$ and $e$ respectively. If there exists a pair of polynomials $(P, Q) \neq (0, 0)$ such that $AP+BQ = 0$, with $\deg P < e$ and $\deg Q < d$, do $A$ and $B$ necessarily have a common root? Why?

(I think they do, and the sources I have access to insinuate this, but don’t prove it.)

## Background

(Let $\mathcal P_i$ denote the $i$-dimensional vector space of polynomials of degree **less** than $i$.)

I’m reading the Wikipedia article about the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition), and it defines the resultant $R(A, B)$ rather elegantly, as the determinant of a linear map $\varphi : \mathcal P_e \times \mathcal P_d \to \mathcal P_{d+e}$ sending $(P, Q)$ to $AP+BQ$, written as a matrix in the basis of powers of $x$:

> If $A=a_0x^d +a_1x^{d-1} + \cdots + a_d$ and $B=b_0x^e +b_1x^{e-1} + \cdots + b_e$ then
>
> $$ R(A, B) = \begin{vmatrix} 
> a_0      &            &  &           & b_0        &               &  &        \\
> a_1    & a_0       &  &            & b_1     & b_0           &  &   \\
> a_2    & a_1     & \ddots &            & b_2     & b_1         & \ddots &  \\
> \vdots  &\vdots   & \ddots & a_0        & \vdots   &\vdots       & \ddots & b_0  \\
> a_d       & a_{d-1} & \ddots & \vdots   & b_e       & b_{e-1}     & \ddots & \vdots\\
>           & a_d       & \ddots &  \vdots  &           & b_e          & \ddots &  \vdots  \\
>   &    & \ddots & a_{d-1}  &   &       & \ddots & b_{e-1}   \\
>           &           &   & a_d       &            &               &  & b_e   
> \end{vmatrix}. $$

From what I know about the resultant, $A$ and $B$ share a root ***precisely*** when this determinant is zero.

From what I know about linear algebra, this means that $A$ and $B$ share a root ***precisely*** when $\ker \varphi \neq 0$: that is, there exist some $(P, Q) \neq (0, 0)$ in $\mathcal P_e \times \mathcal P_d$ such that $AP+BQ=0$. (In fact, assuming this is true, I would expect it to be *the* observation that leads to the above definition of the resultant, and the choice of $\varphi$.)

I can prove this in one direction:

> If $A = a_0 (x-\alpha) A'$ and $B = b_0 (x-\alpha)B'$, then pick $P = b_0 B'$ and $Q = -a_0A'$: it follows that $$AP+BQ = a_0b_0(x-\alpha)A'B' - a_0b_0(x-\alpha)A'B' = 0.$$
>
> Since $\deg P = e-1$ and $\deg Q = d-1$, this choice is valid.

But in the other direction, I’m stuck, leading to the question above.

Comment: what if $P=B$ and $Q=-A$?

Comment: @daw Good point: I had missed the requirement that $(P, Q) \in \mathcal P_e \times \mathcal P_d$ implies $\deg P < e = \deg B$ and $\deg Q < d = \deg A$. I’ve updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$AP=-BQ$$ then one of the factors of $A$ must also be a factor of $B$, by consideration of the degees.

Comment: Ah, I see! Considering the degrees, in $(A, P; B, Q)$ there are respectively $(d, e-1; e, d-1)$ factors. So if both sides have the same factors, then when redistributing the factors from the LHS to the RHS, $Q$ can hold _at most_ $d-1$ factors of $A$, but one of them _must_ end up in $B$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Lynn Well said.